# Problems with version matcher in Ivy

Tags: ivy

I'm trying to resolve an artifact with a version matcher in Ivy. The docs basically say to add this to the ivysettings.xml

```
  <version-matchers>
    <pattern-vm>
      <match revision="foo" pattern="${major}\.${minor}\.\d+" args="major, minor" matcher="regexp" />
    </pattern-vm>
    </version-matchers>
```

and this to your ivy.xml

```
<dependency org="com.example" name="test" rev="foo(1, 3)" />
```

However, this is the error message I get when doing this:

```
Impossible to resolve dependencies of com.example#com.example;working@XX81111L
unresolved dependency: com.example#test;foo(1,0): not found
unresolved dependency: com.example#test;foo(1,0): not found
```

What could I be missing here?

Comment: What file pattern are you trying to match? I've never needed to use this advanced ivy feature. I'd suggest reading the ivy test doco for a working example

Comment: Well, 1.3.123 should resolve with this example, but it doesn't seem to even be trying to use the version matcher at all. I've tried even simpler patterns like ${major} and it doesn't work. I've tried finding more documentation on this, but without much luck.

Comment: forgive me. Why do you need to specify a version matcher? What is the problem you're trying to solve that requires this feature?

Comment: I don't anymore actually, I was just trying it out and expecting it to work. I've since used version ranges in ivy to achieve my desired functionality.

Comment: did you find the solution anyway by any chance?